# How to return only numbers that divide by 3 in iterable form within class using iterator

Tags: python, iterator

I've started to learn iterators am trying to implement them myself.
I have created a class that should provide numbers within a range from user defined start to user defined end, in an iterable form.

Now my code looks like this:

```
class Can_be_divided_by_three:
  def __init__(self, start, end):
      self.start = start
      self.end = end

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.start > self.end:
      raise StopIteration
    item = self.start
    self.start += 1
    if item % 3 == 0:
      return item

iterator = Can_be_divided_by_three(3, 8)
print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
```

And this is the output:
3
None
None
6

So actually there is output even if the number is not divided by 3 and it is None.
Am I getting this wrong, and if yes, how to get it right? I actually need the only output in the form of number divisible by 3 with iteration capabilities.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not find the lowest multiple of 3 in the range and then increment by 3? Testing the non-multiples just wastes CPU time.

Comment: That's a good point, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your logic **next** method will return the number if the number is divisible by 3 but you have not specified what this function should do if the number is not divisible by three, so try below code:

```
class Can_be_divided_by_three:
  def __init__(self, start, end):
      self.start = start
      self.end = end

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    if self.start > self.end:
      raise StopIteration
    item = self.start
    self.start += 1
    if item % 3 == 0:
      return item
    else:
      return self.__next__()      

iterator = Can_be_divided_by_three(3, 8)
print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
print(next(iterator))
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on John Coleman's comment that you only need to find the smallest multiple of 3, you can achieve the same with this:

```py
def Can_be_divided_by_three(start, end):
    while start % 3:
        start += 1
    
    for i in range(start, end, 3):
        yield i
```

Comment: Yes, but this is generator, not an iterator :)

Comment: @vdmclcv You can just turn it into an iterator with, e.g.,`iter(Can_be_divided_by_three(3, 8))` – but would that make any difference?

Comment: not in terms of result, it is totally great. However, as I've said, I'm learning iterators now and have to stick with them. Generators will be my next step

Comment: Ah ok - I should've read your question more carefully. :)

Comment: @vdmclcv Every generator is an iterator! :) But I see the concern; you're looking to implement `__iter__` and the like manually.

Comment: @MustafaAydın yes, exactly, hence my comment, but the OP is doing this as an exercise so from an implementation perspective he's absolutely right!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and involvement

Answer (score 0):

You only return item if `item % 3 == 0`.
You should return something else in other scenarios if you want to avoid `None`s

Comment: Well, my goal is to iterate only through numbers divisible by 3. If I return something else, this will also get into output the way I get None. I understand why I do get it, but I need to avoid output totally if the number is not divisible by 3

Comment: @vdmclcv then instead of printing `next(iterator)` every time, check if it is not `None`, and if it is not `None`, print it out.

Answer (score 0):

The code which you have written is right and would return number divisible by 3 within user defined range. The reason you are finding `None` in the output is because of the `print()` function.
Try running the only `next(iterator)`. In Jupyter the iterator returns only 3 & 6